# Invoking a Button Click Event of UserControl from its parent Form using Function Keys Like (F3,F6)

Tags: c#

Code in User Control (Windows User Control).

I have a button and when click on the button some logic will fire.

below is button event.

```
 private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     // Some Logic
 }
```

I have Main form (Windows form)

I am adding the above user control in a Panel of my Main Winform.
From here I want to invoke the user control `btnCancel_Click` event using some function Keys Like (F3,F4).

This is a very new thing for me. Please help me in this regard.

Thanks .
Krishna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your parent form `KeyPreview` attribute to true and then in the `KeyDown` event of your parent form, look for `if(e.KeyCode == Keys.F3)`, then write a public method for your usercontrol which fires the `btnCancel_Click`. You can access it from your parent form.

Parent Form:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F3)
    {
        MyUserControl.FireButtonEvent();
    }
}
```

Usercontrol:

```
public void FireButtonEvent()
{
  this.btnCancel_Click(null, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `KeyEvent` method. for example:

```
private void KeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string sKey = e.KeyValue.ToString();
    if (sKey==112) {//SomeCode;} // F1
}
```

In the designer code link the method to a key press event on the main form:

`this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.KeyDown);`

Look on the net for the key values of the button you want to activate it,
F1 to F24 are values 112 to 135.